# HTML not changing from JavaScript script

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a basic Average Calculator in HTML and JavaScript. I have the input field and buttons in HTML and the averaging and Reset functions in JavaScript. I cannot find where my problem is.

HTML Code:

```
<section class="script">
  <script src="avg.js"></script>
  <input type="number" id="inputVal" placeholder="Input Value..."></number><br>
  <button id="Btn_Avg" onclick="AddFunc(inputVal.Value)">Average</button>
  <button id="Btn_Rst" onclick="ResetFunc()">Reset</button>
  <p>Average: </p><p id="average">OK</p>
</section>
```

JavaScript script (avg.js):

```
global var count = 0;
global var total = 0;
global var avg = 0;
global var result = document.getElementById("average");
result.textContent = 0;

function AddFunc(value){
  total += value;
  count += 1;
  avg = total / count;
  result.innerHTML = '' + avg;
}

function ResetFunc() {
  total = 0;
  count = 0;
  avg = 0;
  result.innerHTML = '0';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one, it should be `inputVal.value` (lowercase `value`). That should correctly pass the input value to your function. But your question doesn't really describe what issue you're running into, so I'm not sure that answers your question.

Also I don't think `global` is a valid keyword for JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this part `onclick="AddFunc(inputVal.Value)"`. This will not pass value of `inputVal` to the function. You should store the `<input>` element in a variable and access its value using small `v`i.e `value`

```js
var count = 0;
var total = 0;
var avg = 0;
var result = document.getElementById("average");
var input = document.getElementById('inputVal')
result.textContent = 0;

function AddFunc(e){
  let value = Number(input.value);
  total += value;
  count += 1;
  avg = total / count;
  result.innerHTML = '' + avg;
}

function ResetFunc() {
  total = 0;
  count = 0;
  avg = 0;
  result.innerHTML = '0';
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="inputVal" placeholder="Input Value..."></number><br>
  <button id="Btn_Avg" onclick="AddFunc(event)">Average</button>
  <button id="Btn_Rst" onclick="ResetFunc()">Reset</button>
  <p>Average: </p><p id="average">OK</p>
```